# element.className vs element[class~="className"] - What is the difference?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've been trying to understand what exactly is the difference between the following 2 class selectors in CSS

`element.className`

`element[class~="className"]`

My understanding is that in both cases, either selector will look for elements that contain discrete class values that equal the selector, in this case a value of className.

For example:

```
<element class="className" />
<element class="class Name" />
<element class="className className2" />
<element class="class-Name" />
```

- In the above example, only element 1 and 3 would be selected by both selector types. Are there any situations where they would select different elements?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors

Comment: `~=` matches in a list of whitespace-separated "words", so yes, both are pretty much the same. Specificity of both given selectors is also the same.

Answer (score 0):

### Case Sensitivity

One difference between how `element.className` and `element[class~="className"]` could be evaluated is case sensitivity.

> When matching against a document which is in quirks mode, class names must be matched ASCII case-insensitively; class selectors are otherwise case-sensitive, only matching class names they are identical to. - https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#class-html

So `element.className` is case sensitive if you have `<!DOCTYPE html>` at the top of your HTML files, and caSe iNSenSiTiVE if you don't.

> By default case-sensitivity of attribute names and values in selectors depends on the document language - https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#attribute-case

So `element[class~="className"]` depends on the language the document is in. But you can also explicitly set it to case-insensitive `element[class~="className" i]` and case-sensitive `element[class~="className" s]`, note the latter is experimental.

Note that some tooling/browsers may normalize case on you, making all this redundant. Don't use `className` and `classname` and treat them both differently!

### Browser Compatibility

Note that the attribute selector was introduced in CSS 2.1 and the .class selector seems to have been around longer. Both are supported by practically every browser but I'm willing to bet more browsers support the standard `.className` selector than the intricate `~=` attribute syntax (despite the [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/) data)

Comment: Is any document in quirks mode anymore these days?

Comment: @AKX If you forget to add DOCTYPE html anything is possible :D